# How can i persist an accesstoken with ReactJS and ExpressJS API?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, access-token, session-storage

I have weeks working on login functionality, and I am avoiding with persist an user session. I thought about using *LocalStorage*, but it would be vulnerable to CSRF attack, and I don't know how could I do that.

I'm working with React.js(frontend), Express.js (backend)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the user token in `httpOnly cookie`. More details [how-to-secure-jwt-in-a-single-page-application](https://dev.to/nilanth/how-to-secure-jwt-in-a-single-page-application-cko)

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your token before saving in local storage.

After retreiving the token decrypt it and use it.

I use the same method currently.

Comment: I already did that. That's the easy way, but not the securest way.